# How to distinct count an ID only on the first date in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Table where an ID can occur over multiple dates due to having different states.

| ID | State | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 2022-01-01 |
| A | b | 2022-01-02 |
| A | c | 2022-01-03 |
| B | d | 2022-01-01 |
| B | e | 2022-01-02 |
| C | f | 2022-01-03 |

I would like to create **ONE** measure to distinct count the IDs.
This measure is needed for KPI cards, Line Charts and table visuals.
This is easily done with:

```
Count = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID])
```

Displaying this measure in a table visual split by Date.

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| Total | 3 |

A count will appear for each date where this ID occurred. The Total will always be correct.

However, I do not want to distinct count for each date. Just the **first** date at which the ID occurred.

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| Total | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will works fast. Just replace your measure with this one and get a result.

```
MyMeasure = 
VAR t =
    CALCULATETABLE( --new
        VALUES('table'[ID]) --new 
        ,FILTER(
            'table'
            ,VAR dateInRow=[DATE]
                RETURN  
                dateInRow=CALCULATE(
                                    min('table'[DATE])
                                    ,ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[ID]) 
                            )
        )
    ) -- new
VAR result = COUNTROWS(t)          
RETURN 
    IF(
      ISBLANK(result)
      ,0
      ,result
     )
```

Comment: This does not seem to return the right results. The count per day and total is over stated.

Comment: It can be that you have 2 equal ID and dates but different other Values. I'll edit the measure for the case

Comment: I altered the measure, please check

Answer (score 2):

First create a measured column :

```
Dates = calculate ( min('Table'[DATE]), 
               filter('Table','Table'[ID ] = EARLIER('Table'[ID ])))
```

then use your measure with the above column

```
Count = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID ])
```

Comment: Due to data modelling constrains, I need to solve this in a measure. Unable to use Measured Columns.

Comment: this doesn't mean that my answer is not working )))

Comment: True. Your solution does give the correct result. Thank you.
However, I do need it in 1 measure. :)